# Check if there is a session without using session_start()

Tags: php

I want to check if a person has an active session and redirect them to another page when they have one. However, I do not want to use **session_start()**, as that will place a cookie on the persons PC (I do not want to place cookies on peoples' PC when they're not logged in). Is there a way to check for an existing session, without placing a cookie on their PC?

Comment: Using `session_start` is fine.  It doesn't matter if you put a cookie on the user's PC if they're not logged in.

Comment: Maybe a needless cookie on the client is not a big deal, but `session_start` will also create an empty session file on the server (which also will have to be GC-ed at some point later). So it's not for free.

Answer (score 8):

You can check for the existence of the session ID cookie, which the client would send back if it had been previous set elsewhere in your site:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
   ... most likely there's a session available to be loaded ...
}
```

For added safety, you could then check for the existence of the session file (assuming you're using the default file-based handler) using `session_save_path()` and the `session_name()` to build up a path to pass into `file_exists()`

Comment: +1 | note to Aaron: notice Marc says **likely** a session available. if the session has not yet expired, but your server has terminated the session on it's end, `isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])` will still return true. The users browser will send the cookie as it has no way of initially telling whether or not the session has been prematurely terminated.

Comment: I think this method not ensure you if the session is still active or not. 
Could be the case where the client sends the cookie, the file on server still 
exists but is already marked as expired. When the GC runs, the file will be 
deleted!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. How would I check if the session is expired?

Comment: @Aaron: Use the `session_start()` way :)

Comment: Thanks again. I figured that if there was an old session cookie the people already did give me (unneeded) permission to place a cookie on their PC.

Comment: If the session's expired, then the session file won't exist

Answer (score 2):

You can either check against the function `session_id()`, which will return the current session ID for the user, or an empty string if no session exists:

```
if (empty(session_id())) {
  /* redirect or logic here here, example: */
  header('location:path/to/your/session/start/page');
  exit();
}
```

Or you can check that the session cookie/global variable is set (`isset($_SESSION)` or `isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]`. Doc for `session_id()` [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

Answer (score 2):

Test this first, but I think `session_id() != ""` will give true if there's a session and false if not.

Comment: You don't need the `!` outside the parenthesis, just do `session_id() != ""`, or better yet `!empty(session_id())`.

Comment: `session_id()` seems to always return an empty string to me, even if I have an active session.