# session_start() returns set-cookie header even if I don't store anything in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a `check_login` function that does a `session_start()` in order to check if the user is logged in or not.
if the user is not logged in, the page is returning a set-cookie header with a PHPSESSID
is there a way to disable this set-cookie header when I do not store any variables in the $_SESSION variable?

The reason why I don't want this set-cookie header is because I'm implementing a reverse proxy server (varnish)

Comment: Start a session, get a session cookie. Sounds logical to me.

Comment: Or you could adapt your code logic to only start the session when you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question here:

[Check if there is a session without using session_start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966156/check-if-there-is-a-session-without-using-session-start)

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
   ... most likely there's a session available to be loaded ...
}
```

Comment: This is predicated on not creating a session prior to an authentication attempt - which was not stated as part of the original question and is a rather unusual scenario. However it's a very strange combination that you know you're not creating a session until authentication *and* you want to check whether or not you have (not) created the session

Answer (score 0):

Only if the session id is passed in the url, which is not a good idea.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

Comment: but why does it need to set a cookie? I'm not using the session.. I just need to check if the user is logged in or not

Comment: You use the session, you are starting it. Once the session is started a cookie is set on the client with the session id so it can be remembered for that client unless you use the url.

Comment: how about destroying the session if it doesn't contain any data? I just thought of that.. using session_destroy()